# How to check time spent by mod_rewrite when rewrite urls?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My question is simple:

Is it possible to know the time elapsed when apache mod_rewrite rewrite urls ?

My site has about 20 million requests/month.

In this case, I want to know the time spent in these rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Remove Multiple slashes in betweeen
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
  RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

  # Send everything to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some_path/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move rewriting to VirtualHost configuration if possible, so regular expressions are not compiled for each request in .htaccess.
For example, for Apache, in httpd.conf place your content of .htaccess like this:

```
<Directory /www/htdocs/example>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      # Remove Multiple slashes in betweeen
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
      RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

      # Send everything to index.php
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some_path/index.php/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, my rules aren't in the project root, I place this in the Virtual Host configuration for prevent parsing the file (.htaccess) in every request

Comment: You set .htaccess as keyword so I thought you did.

Comment: Sorry, I put this keyword for greater visibility.

Comment: No problem. If you already have directives in conf, you don't have much space for improvements :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check the "waiting" time in Firebug or other Browser tools to check how much time is spent between the request and your browser actually receives data.

Redirecting to static ressources would of course be better to avoid evaluating the time PHP takes to process the request.

Of coure it will still include the time Apache normally spends treating the request and you probably want to test both scenarios: with redirect and without.

BTW, if you're looking to optimize these, you could try replacing this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

With this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)//(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

There's no real need to use this kind of rewritecond alone, a more complex rewrite rule is enough.

Also,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some_path/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Can be replaced with

```
RewriteRule (.*) some_path/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Starting and ending character won't be sent in $1 so it can be included in the rule, hence simplifying it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but at the server level there is no way to check it?

Comment: You can activate some rewriting log but it will probably slow down the requests, as mentionned in the documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging . As a result, you won't get a clear picture of how much time is really spent on these.

Comment: Yes, log isn't a good way, but I think to test this, I will perform about 1000 equal requests to a static page without code inside and calculate the spent time.

Comment: You should also reduce backtracking and repeated redirects: `^(([^/]+/)*)/+(.*)$`

Comment: Gumbo, you refer to the first rule for "Remove Multiple Slashes"?